# Android code to receive data from non-android bluetooth device

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am going through a scenario in which I need to receive data from a NON-Android device (say, a PC with Bluetooth Dongle). I need to display my own UI and want to handle the incoming data by my application itself. So is there any good way to achieve this goal.

***--Edit***

*As @Trevor mentioned in his answer, the following para have no meaning, I only understood the fact after a little long study about the topic. Anyway, Thanks for all for there suggestions.*

So far I tried with `listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(...)` and `createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(...)` but in this way, we need to run our application in both the devices. Currently its not my case.

***--Edit***

So, is there any good way to receive data from a NON-Android device?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I found [this link ](http://english.cxem.net/arduino/arduino5.php) very useful, it shows how to send as well as receive data from Arduino to/from Android.

Comment: Have you got a solution for this ,if so please post your idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little vague because you haven't explained exactly what problems have occurred when you've tried to connect to whatever Bluetooth device it is you're trying to use. Your second paragraph (*"So far I tried with listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(...) and createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(...) but in this way, we need to run our application in both the devices. Currently its not my case."*) doesn't make sense to me.

However, I'm assuming it's a SPP device you're trying to connect to (that is, a Bluetooth to Serial interface, or a USB PC Bluetooth dongle set up with a virual COM port). In this case, you can use the Bluetooth Chat example code pretty much as it is, except for one important change which is to use the SPP UUID:

```
/** UUID for Serial Port Profile */
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
```

By the way, if you use the Bluetooth Chat example as the basis of your project, beware of a bug I found in the Bluetooth Chat code which causes received characters to be lost if they're received at anything faster that typing speed. For information on this, refer to my answer given here: [Android InputStream dropping first two bytes (modified BluetoothChat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239692/android-inputstream-dropping-first-two-bytes-modified-bluetoothchat/12288979#12288979)

Comment: Thanks for your time @Trevor. I'm new to android Bluetooth app development, and I'm learning about SPP for the first time. I would like to know also, whether the SPP UUID will be always same as you mentioned in your code sample?

Comment: You can safely use only this UUID to communicate with a wide range of SPP Bluetooth devices. I have an automotive application on Play that is used with all sorts of different Bluetooth to serial adapters and this UUID has been fine. Another important thing to be aware of though is that with some devices you will need to use the reflection method to connect.

Answer (score 0):

in android sdk sample take a Look at the BluetoothChat,

you need two thread to communicate the data

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        this.mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString(SPP_UUID));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        setName("ConnectThread");
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        try {
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            connectionFailed();
            return;

        }
        synchronized (PrinterService.this) {
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
        connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("PrinterService", "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}

private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Printer Service", "temp sockets not created", e);
        }
        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                if (!encodeData(mmInStream)) {
                    mState = STATE_NONE;
                    connectionLost();
                    break;
                } else {
                }
                // mHandler.obtainMessage(AbstractActivity.MESSAGE_READ,
                // bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                connectionLost();
                PrinterService.this.stop();
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: This is an example to communicate between 2 Android devices both running the same Application with a unique UUID. I am asking for a solution to receive data from a NON-Android device. So, I think this is not I want. But, thanks for the immediate help.

Comment: I  dont think this is only for android device only, I am using this for connection my android mobile to bluetooth printer and its working fine

Comment: Ok, then from where I can get the server service UUID, as of here it is 'SPP_UUID'. As I mentioned already, I'm going to connect my android device with a Bluetoot dongle attached to a PC. So from where I can get the UUID for 'createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(...)'?

Comment: check out the documentation here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(java.util.UUID)