# Bluetooth data loss between Android and Arduino

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, byte, buffer

Straight to the point - my application due to some mysterious reason looses part of a data (String) when receiving an InputStream. I am talking about Bluetooth connection here. Most of the time, I am receiving correct string but once in while it is shortened. Weirdest thing in here is that I am printing every InputStream into my ScrollView and I can tell that the whole string is there... Nevertheless here is the code:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    InputStream inputStream;

    try {
        inputStream = mBTSocket.getInputStream();
        while (!bStop) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            int bytes;
            if (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                bytes = inputStream.read(buffer);
                final String strInput = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);;

                mTxtReceive.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mTxtReceive.append(strInput);

                        int txtLength = mTxtReceive.getEditableText().length();
                        if (txtLength > mMaxChars) {
                            mTxtReceive.getEditableText().delete(0, txtLength - mMaxChars);
                        }

                        scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
                            }
                        });
                        }
                    });

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        weather = strInput.split(",");
                        mTxtHumidity.setText(weather[0]);
                        mTxtTemperatureDHT.setText(weather[1]);
                        mTxtPressure.setText(weather[2]);
                        mTxtLux.setText(weather[3]);
                        mTxtRainMM.setText(weather[4]);
                        mTxtRainDaily.setText(weather[5]);
                        mTxtWSKPH.setText(weather[6]);
                        mTxtWGKPH.setText(weather[7]);
                        mTxtWSAVG2.setText(weather[8]);
                        mTxtWGAVG10.setText(weather[9]);

                    }
                });
            }
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The problem in here is null exception on array `weather` as according to my app I am sometimes accessing items out of boundry (`weather` length is 6/7/8 most of the time once it errors). App crashes in 10% of the time.

Any reason behind it?

EDIT: while receiving InputStream sometimes instead of receiving 56 bytes I get 33 and 22 separetely

Comment: What android version are you using?

Comment: I am using 4.4.2 version, SGS4

Comment: maybe you could check if your buffer is the right size. If not, repeat the network transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to be found here: [Android InputStream dropping first two bytes (modified BluetoothChat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239692/android-inputstream-dropping-first-two-bytes-modified-bluetoothchat/12264498#12264498)

Adding

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(100);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

solves only for non-dynamic data exchange between Android and Arduino due to `sleep` method. It turns out that even `sleep(50)` works in this condition. For some reason after this short `sleep` buffer is never divided nor lost. If it is bad coding please explain before downvoting.