# Why does Android Bluetooth socket keep reading the same messages?

Tags: android, networking, bluetooth

I'm writing an app that uses androids BluethoothSocket class and BluetoothServerSocket.  Currently i'm testing with two devices, one the server and one the client and I'm trying to implement my app specific messages their formats are like this;

`[1byte MessageType][2byte length of whole message][1byte clientID][XXXbytes whatever data specific to this message]`

So the above "header" portion is what im parsing from the socket to see how i should interpret what i received.  The  problem is im getting the same messages a bunch of times in a row.  And unless im missing logic somewhere i dont think its my app sending it this many times. It based on a request/response cycle so it really only should happen when a certain action gets triggered. For example,

user connects
server -> sends client his ID
client -> sends response (i got your message. server can stop sending it)

Am I missing any nuances about the BluetoothSocket class or just basic networking protocols in general? It just seems like the socket is reading the same message over and over even when it is not being sent.  My servers read function looks like this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[BTUtils.MAX_SOCKET_READ]; // byte[2048]
        int bytes;
        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (m_state == BTStates.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = m_inputStream.read(buffer);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                m_uiHandler.obtainMessage(BTMessages.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                disconnectClient(m_clientId);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are ignoring end of stream. If `read()` returns -1, the peer has disconnected; there is no data in the buffer; and you should close the socket.

Comment: @EJP Thanks. I probably should be handling the -1 return from the read function but that doesn't really sound like it deals with my problem.  In fact, it's almost the opposite I'm actually repeatedly getting valid byte counts from the read function.

Comment: It was a comment not an answer. Are you sure the client isn't sending > 1 message?

Comment: @EJP  I actually posted an answer that worked for me.  I was processing a buffer that was the same one being read into by the socket and it was causing the issues.   I changed my code to make a copied byte array of the received bytes by the socket and am now processing that and my problems went away.

Answer (score 0):

So guys after some more googling and looking on stack overflow I came across my answer here:

[Android InputStream dropping first two bytes (modified BluetoothChat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239692/android-inputstream-dropping-first-two-bytes-modified-bluetoothchat)

> I have seen people run into this sort of problem before when using the Bluetooth Chat example. The problem with the example code is that the message object that is sent to the Handler simply contains a reference to the actual byte[] array that is used for each subsequent read() operation. This means that as soon as the Handler obtains the message and starts inspecting the array, the subsequent read() operation on the Bluetooth socket has already had the opportunity to write newer data to that array.

Even though the OP of that post had 2 bytes from his stream it looked like a similar problem to what I was experiencing where sometimes the messages would be all jumbled up and weird looking.  I'm actually going to look into a circular buffer solution because i think eventually I will need it.  But future posters careful with the bluetooth example if you aren't familiar with bluetooth technology (like me).